# Using background color for different shades

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a background color as multiple shades? I think it is possible, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. And also making sure it's the right color:

CSS:

```
.background {
   background-color: #3ea2ab; 
   border: 1px solid;       
   height: 310px;
}
```

but making the background color in different shades.. Something like

Obviously "main shade" isn't an element. But I'm trying to get you guys to understand what I'm saying..

```
    background-color: main shade
    background-color: main shade light color
    background-color: main shade lighter color
```

if you know what i mean? Here's an example: 
[image: screencloud image]
(it looks like this images uses different shades of that color)

I'm trying to avoid images if I can.

Comment: Are you talking about a gradient? If so, use that word as a search term for your next search...

Comment: Did you try using gradient?

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Flinear-gradient).
Gradients can easily be made with CSS:

```css
body, html{
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#55B6BF, #3EA2AB); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#55B6BF, #3EA2AB); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#55B6BF, #3EA2AB); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#55B6BF, #3EA2AB); /* Standard syntax */
 background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: What generator did you go to to get this?

Comment: @Yabo None :D its just the basic gradient css i use(i think it is originally w3schools) and i just got the collors with an eyedropper

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
background: rgb(62,162,171); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(62,162,171,1) 0%, rgba(0,158,195,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(62,162,171,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,158,195,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(62,162,171,1) 0%,rgba(0,158,195,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(62,162,171,1) 0%,rgba(0,158,195,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(62,162,171,1) 0%,rgba(0,158,195,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(62,162,171,1) 0%,rgba(0,158,195,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3ea2ab', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

This was generated from http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ 
you can achieve the same as

```
 background-color: main shade
 background-color: main shade light color
 background-color: main shade lighter color
```

by adding color stops to the gradient.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/cL5tc37x/6/